# Is $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=2\cos(x)\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+2\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x\right)$ new?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, plane-geometry

When I research my discovered [my generalization of the Simson line](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90%E1%BB%8Bnh_l%C3%BD_%C4%90%C3%A0o_(m%E1%BB%9F_r%E1%BB%99ng_%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng_th%E1%BA%B3ng_Simson)#:%7E:text=%C4%90%E1%BB%8Bnh%20l%C3%BD%20%C4%90%C3%A0o%20(m%E1%BB%9F%20r%E1%BB%99ng%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng%20th%E1%BA%B3ng%20Simson)%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t,%C4%91%E1%BB%8Bnh%20l%C3%BD%20%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng%20th%E1%BA%B3ng%20Simson.):

I found the Identity trigonometric as follows:

$$ \cos^2 \left( x \right) = 2\cos\left( x \right) \cos\left( y\right) \cos\left( x+y+\frac{\pi}{3} \right) + \sin^2\left( x+y \right) + 2\sin\left( x+y \right) \cos\left(y \right) \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{3} - x \right) $$

Let $y=0$ the identity become nice identity as follows:

$$\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=2\cos(x)\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+2\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x\right)$$

**My question:** Is the identity new, and how can it prove?

Answer (score 2):

To prove the identity which only involves $x$, we can note that
\begin{align*}
\cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right) &= \cos x \cos \frac{\pi}3 - \sin x \sin \frac{\pi}3 = \frac12 \cos x - \frac{\sqrt3}2 \sin x \\ \sin \left( \frac\pi3 - x \right) &= \sin \frac\pi3 \cos x - \cos \frac\pi3 \sin x = \frac{\sqrt3}2 \cos x - \frac12 \sin x
\end{align*}
This gives us
\begin{align*}
2 \cos x \cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right) &= \cos^2 x - \sqrt{3} \cos x \sin x \\
2 \sin x \sin \left( \frac \pi3 - x \right) &= \sqrt3 \cos x \sin x - \sin^2 x
\end{align*}
Adding these two together yields $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$, which is the left hand side of the equation.

For another proof, we can observe that
\begin{align*}
1 &= 2 \cos \frac\pi 3 = 2 \cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 -x \right) = 2 \cos x \cos \left( \frac\pi3 - x\right) - 2 \sin x \sin \left( \frac\pi3 - x \right) \\
1 &= 2 \cos \left( -\frac\pi3 \right) = 2 \cos \left( x + -\frac\pi3 - x \right) = 2 \cos x \cos \left( -\frac\pi3 - x \right) - 2 \sin x \sin \left( - \frac\pi3 - x \right) \\
&= 2 \cos x \cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right) + 2 \sin x \sin \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right)
\end{align*}
Subtracting the first equation from the second and rearranging gives us
$$2 \cos x \cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right)+2 \sin x \sin \left(\frac\pi3 - x \right) = 2 \cos x \cos \left( \frac\pi3 - x\right) - 2 \sin x \sin \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right)$$
Adding up the two sides of this equation gives
\begin{align*}
&2 \cos \left( 2x + \frac\pi3 \right) + 2 \cos \left( 2x - \frac\pi 3 \right) \\&= 2 \cos 2x \cdot \frac12 - 2 \sin 2x \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}2 + 2 \cos 2x \cdot \frac12 + 2 \sin 2x \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}2 \\
&= 2 \cos 2x
\end{align*}
Since the two sides of the equation above are equal, they must each be equal to half of their sum, whence
$$2 \cos x \cos \left( x + \frac\pi3 \right) + 2 \sin x \sin \left( \frac\pi3 - x \right) = \cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$$

Comment: Do you give your proof the first I dentity?

Comment: The first identity can be proven by applying the cosine-of-a-sum and sine-of-a-sum formulas several times as I did in my first proof of the second identity. There is likely a cleaner method, but this will definitely work out. Did you arrive at these two identities through calculations with your generalization of the Simson line? If so, you may already have a proof on your hands.

Comment: I want give my proof generalization of the Simson line, I need prove the first identity, but I can not. I posted in here since 2013: https://mathscope.org/showthread.php?p=191047#post191047 If you give a proof. You can give a new proof of the generalization of the Simson line.

Comment: I urge you to try to prove it on your own: use the identities $\cos(x+y) = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$ and $\sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$ to expand the right hand side, and if your identity holds, then you'll find that many terms cancel and you end up with just $\cos^2 x$.